# How to iterate over JSON

Tags: visualforce, json

I have an integration with a third system with the following JSON as response:

```
{"result":{"code":200,"info":"OK"},"data":[{"date":"201501","avg":50.56258,"max":5697.46,"min":0.01,"std":147.57,"peak_txs_day":6,"valley_txs_day":3,"peak_txs_hour":13,"valley_txs_hour":5,"merchants":709,"cards":9534,"txs":18115},{"date":"201502","avg":51.91523,"max":8716.21,"min":0.03,"std":162.79,"peak_txs_day":3,"valley_txs_day":4,"peak_txs_hour":13,"valley_txs_hour":4,"merchants":712,"cards":9281,"txs":17671},{"date":"201503","avg":50.40081,"max":4279.98,"min":0.26,"std":131.05,"peak_txs_day":3,"valley_txs_day":6,"peak_txs_hour":13,"valley_txs_hour":3,"merchants":738,"cards":9594,"txs":18534},{"date":"201504","avg":50.78692,"max":5802.34,"min":0.01,"std":135.89,"peak_txs_day":5,"valley_txs_day":6,"peak_txs_hour":13,"valley_txs_hour":5,"merchants":731,"cards":9244,"txs":17606},{"date":"201505","avg":52.47475,"max":4215.71,"min":0.01,"std":140.75,"peak_txs_day":1,"valley_txs_day":5,"peak_txs_hour":12,"valley_txs_hour":4,"merchants":747,"cards":10001,"txs":19259},{"date":"201506","avg":57.75459,"max":5783.51,"min":0.01,"std":169.48,"peak_txs_day":2,"valley_txs_day":6,"peak_txs_hour":12,"valley_txs_hour":4,"merchants":757,"cards":10776,"txs":20024},{"date":"201507","avg":56.72582,"max":14797.81,"min":0.01,"std":184.3,"peak_txs_day":5,"valley_txs_day":3,"peak_txs_hour":12,"valley_txs_hour":4,"merchants":730,"cards":9785,"txs":17697},{"date":"201508","avg":50.77434,"max":6815.92,"min":0.01,"std":146.59,"peak_txs_day":7,"valley_txs_day":3,"peak_txs_hour":12,"valley_txs_hour":4,"merchants":623,"cards":7035,"txs":11658},{"date":"201509","avg":51.8787,"max":3867.77,"min":0.01,"std":131.23,"peak_txs_day":4,"valley_txs_day":7,"peak_txs_hour":13,"valley_txs_hour":4,"merchants":746,"cards":10059,"txs":18222},{"date":"201510","avg":50.79373,"max":4805.15,"min":0.01,"std":132.93,"peak_txs_day":5,"valley_txs_day":3,"peak_txs_hour":12,"valley_txs_hour":3,"merchants":761,"cards":10676,"txs":19831}]}
```

I need to print that in a Visualforce, and I am trying in the following way:

Controller:

```
public PageReference getBasicStatsByZipcode(){
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://apis.bbva.com/paystats_sbx/4/zipcodes/' + zipcode + '/basic_stats?min_date=201501&max_date=201510');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setHeader('Authorization' , 'jwt ' + token);

    //Send the request
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    System.debug(response.getBody());
    if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){

        /***
        * Untyped Parsing of JSON Objects
        ***/

        //creo un mapa con el JSON obtenido
        zipcodeMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        system.debug('zipcodeMap: ' + zipcodeMap);

        //creo una lista para almacenar el array de data
        list<Object> lstData = (list<Object>)zipcodeMap.get('data');
        system.debug('lstData: ' + lstData);
        Object[] arrayData = (Object[])zipcodeMap.get('data');
        system.debug('arrayData: ' + arrayData);
        for(Object data:lstData){
            //obtengo los valores de array data
            //Map<String, Object> dataAttributes = (Map<String, Object>)data;
            dataAttributes = (Map<String, Object>)data;
            system.debug('dataAttributes: ' + dataAttributes);
            //iteramos sobre los atributos de este valor del array
            for(String attributeName:dataAttributes.keySet()){
                System.debug('========> ' + attributeName + ' = ' + 
         dataAttributes.get(attributeName));
            }
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

VisualForce:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Zipcode Services - Basic Stats">

    <apex:repeat value="{!dataAttributes}" var="data">
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!data}" id="theValue" for="data"/>
        <apex:outputText value="{!dataAttributes[data]}" id="data"/><br/>
    </apex:repeat>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

But I am getting only 1 record:

[image]

Could you help me on that? Maybe the approach I'm trying is not the right one, feel free to suggest a better one, the idea is being able to populate the data in a table and use in chart also.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are assigning it new value. Instead you need to push new value in map and keep the old value.

```
dataAttributes = (Map<String, Object>)data;
```

so change this line into

```
dataAttributes.putAll((Map<String, Object>)data);
```

also if not already initialized then you need to initialize this map as well.
`dataAttributes = new Map<String, Object>()` before the for loop.

If you want you can also use wrapper class to parse the response.

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//
public class ExtResponse {

public class ExtResponse {
    public Result result;
    public List<Data> data;
}

public class Data {
    public String date;
    public Double avg;
    public Double max;
    public Double min;
    public Double std;
    public Integer peak_txs_day;
    public Integer valley_txs_day;
    public Integer peak_txs_hour;
    public Integer valley_txs_hour;
    public Integer merchants;
    public Integer cards;
    public Integer txs;
}

public class Result {
    public Integer code;
    public String info;
}


public static ExtResponse parse(String json) {
    return (ExtResponse) System.JSON.deserialize(json, ExtResponse.class);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Tushar Sharma, I tested both approaches and the first one is not working, but the second one seems to work properly. Thanks for your support!